# UTF-8 encoding not working properly php

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

When I try to print a string from a DB the spanish accent is turned into `?` .

Example `de f?tbol, salones para actividades. ?Para m?s informaci?n`
I have tried following things

added 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Then I tried using `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()` none of these things have worked.

I checked int he database the string is properly saved but when I print on the browser it is not printing properly.

Also in my Mysql DB I have `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbSelect);` added.

I think it is some kind of MySql error .

**Update1**

This is happening only when I do query using Join operation

```
SELECT xxxx1.tag,xxxx1.registro,xxxx1.valor FROM campofeed ".
        "INNER JOIN registrofeed ON xxx.id = xxxx1.registro ".
        "WHERE xxxx.feed='xxx' and xxxx.id='xxxxx'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `mysql_set_charset`, i.e.:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
//the rest of the code...
```

Comment: what character encoding do your have on your browser ? it should be unicode. On firefox go to `View -> Character Encoding`

Comment: How to check that in my Dreamweaver it says Unicode utf-8 at the bottom right corner but I do not know how to check this in Browser

Answer (score 2):

Try this header in first line of php:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the encode type of your file. Save as UTF-8. I always check on notepad++.

Comment: You can set a default charset in php  `ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');`

Comment: Have you tried these queries on MySQL?  `SET character_set_client = charset_name;
SET character_set_results = charset_name;
SET character_set_connection = charset_name;`

Comment: should I execute all the above lines in one query ?

Comment: yes, but I think this query `SET NAMES 'charset_name'` will have the same effect as these three. Try to execute this in your php script before your queries.

Comment: I have a class that does the mysql query so I executed like this  `$db->execute("SET NAMES 'charset_name'")`  error unkonwn character set

Comment: like this `mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES utf8");`. It always worked for me.

Comment: yes I added that in my class but still the same result